# Add a 'Show More' card in a carousel with botframework

Tags: node.js, carousel, botframework

Hi! I'm making a carousel using botframework but I have too much cards (±50) to display and it's not userfriendly.

I have an idea: What about display 5-10 cards and then a last one noted: 'Show More'.

The problem:

I know I can do it with an hero card 'action' which launch another message/carousel where I can display the other cards.

But it's not very beautiful and my dream is that when the user click on the 'Show More' button, new cards appear in the same carousel.

Is that possible?
If yes, how?

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of cards able to be shown is channel dependent and not a managed feature in Bot Framework. As such, the feature you are thinking may work in some instances but will be broken in others.

Comment: Thanks. I made an other way (choiceSet of categories THEN display cards of the selected category). However, if the solution exists I'll use it.

Comment: Hi I have adding special card like "previous" and "next" card and some piece of code to wrapp thoses special user choice.

Comment: Can you be more precise? Where did you add it? Thanks.